# json api controller for woocommerce category images

Tags: php, json, object, woocommerce, categories

I try to use json api to get some woocommerce data. With the regular wp jason api i can use custom post type 'product' to get most of my postdata but i also need the category data, like name and specially category images. For this i figured to write a simple controller around the funtion get_terms( 'product_cat'). I bet it is my lack of php oop knowledge where i fail to add the key (image), value (image_url). I get as far as adding only the last image pair details to my json but i would really like to find these details for each category object as an image value in between all the other key,value pairs

Here is my controller:

```
        <?php

        /*
         Controller name: WooCommerce Category Images
         Controller description: Get Woocommmerce category images controller
         */

        final class JSON_API_woocatimages_Controller {

          public function info() {
            return array(
              'version' => '1.0'
            );
          }

           public function get_category_images() {
            $args = array(
                'number'     => $number,
                'orderby'    => $orderby,
                'order'      => $order,
                'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
                'include'    => $ids
            );

            $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
            foreach( $product_categories as $cat ) { 

            // get the thumbnail id user the term_id
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
            // get the image URL
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
            // here i probably do something wrong.....
            $product_categories['image'] = $image;

            }
            return array(
                "WooCommerce Categories" => $product_categories
            );

           }
        }
```

Here's the result: http://funshopping.mystagingwebsite.com/api/woocatimages/get_category_images/

I could use some help on either how to add these image data for each product_categories array AND/OR how to do this differently with the standard json api methods like maybe 'get_category_index'. To be honest i have no clue who to use it other than to get the category index back. It's the same with the controller i have seen on how to get the menu index back but what i would like is to be able to get the values and the id's of the actual menu's being used. I am sure i am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller should be:

```
            <?php

        /*
         Controller name: WooCommerce Category Images
         Controller description: Get Woocommmerce category images controller
         */

        final class JSON_API_woocatimages_Controller {

          public function info() {
            return array(
              'version' => '1.0'
            );
          }

           public function get_category_images() {
            $args = array(
                'number'     => $number,
                'orderby'    => $orderby,
                'order'      => $order,
                'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
                'include'    => $ids
            );

            $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
            foreach( $product_categories as $cat ) { 

            // get the thumbnail id user the term_id
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
            // get the image URL
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 

            $cat->{'image'}=$image;

            }

            return array(
                "WooCommerce Categories" => $product_categories
            );

           }
        }
```